# Set fonts in graphs equal to tex document

Tags: fonts, tex-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set fonts in matplotlib graphs equal to tex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30998/set-fonts-in-matplotlib-graphs-equal-to-tex-document)

I am writing my phd in LaTeX and I am generating all my graphical content in Python with the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)package. For my TeX document, I am using a math-supported font -- e.g. [Kurier Light Condensed](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kurierlc/) -- and I would like to use the same font in my plots.

What is the easiest way to use the same font in my matplotlib figures and my corpus text in LaTeX?

- e.g. can I save my figures (vectorized ?) such that it takes the tex font when importing in tex?
- e.g. can I import the font in matplotlib and use it there?

Comment: The problem seems to be solveable with [matplotlib2tikz][1], by ending the matplotlib script with

> tikz_save( 'myfile.tikz' )

instead of 

> pyplot.show()

Comment: Have you had a look at the [matplotlib page here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html) for using tex rendering for fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be solveable with [matplotlib2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz), by end the matplotlib script with

```
tikz_save( 'myfile.tikz' )
```

instead of

```
pyplot.show()
```