# concrete font for text in matplotlib

Tags: fonts, matplotlib

I have matplotlib figures with labels, which are included as PDF in LaTeX document. I would like label text match with the font of the text, which is concrete (via `\usepackage{concrete}`).

I can change math font in labels with

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'\usepackage{euler}']
```

but adding `\usepackage{concrete}` has no effect on the text font (probably since the default Helvetica is used regardless). [usetex documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html) does not mention concrete to be supported directly.

I also have the `cm-unicode` opentype variants of CMU fonts (CMU Concrete) installed, in case that could be of any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not answer your question directly, but is perhaps a possible workaround:

As I mentioned in [Set fonts in matplotlib graphs equal to tex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30998/set-fonts-in-matplotlib-graphs-equal-to-tex-document/30999#30999) you can perhaps export your plot with the script [`matplotlib2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz). This gives you a `.tex` file with a `TikZ`/`pgfplots` figure that can be input in your document. This will use the same fonts as the document.

**Edit:**
For reference, here is a brief explanation of installation and use.

Having downloaded the files from github, navigate to the folder in a command line, and run `python setup.py install` to install `matplotlib2tikz`.

In your Python script add `from matplotlib2tikz import matplotlib2tikz`, and add `matplotlib2tikz('filename.tex')` after your plot, e.g.

```
from numpy import arange
from matplotlib2tikz import matplotlib2tikz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = arange(0,10,0.5)

plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.title("A lovely plot")
plt.ylabel("$y=x^2$")
matplotlib2tikz('test.tex')
```

You can also specify the width and height of the plot in the Python script, as mentioned in the readme of `matplotlib2tikz`.

Comment: Very nice! In addition, it will work with any possible fonts. Thanks.