# can (pdf)LaTeX change the font in a figure at compilation time

Tags: python, fonts, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set fonts in matplotlib graphs equal to tex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30998/set-fonts-in-matplotlib-graphs-equal-to-tex-document)

I create figures using *Python / Matplotlib* and saved them in *.pdf* and *.eps* format.

I'm writing a (long and complex) .tex document in which I include these figures.

I compile the .tex file with *pdflatex*.

**I'd like to know if it is possible that, when I compile, (pdf)LaTeX automatically "reads" the text in the figure (labels, title, etc.) and "update" their font to the one I use in the .tex document?**

I know *psfrag* can do it, but you have to precise what to change exactly and it doesn't work with pdflatex.

I know *pdfrag* can do it, but you have to precise what to change exactly and it doesn't work for large and complicated files.

**What I'm looking for is a way to automatically and systematically change the font for all text in the .pdf or .eps figures.** (Because I can't afford the time to re-run the code that generated the figures, but I would really like to have nice and uniform font in my document, including the figures).

Remark 1: I generated some figures already using LaTeX fonts thanks to Matplotlib, however, some (if not most) of my figures use the basic (by default) Python/Matplotlib font.

Remark 2: My preamble includes (among others):

```
\usepackage{pslatex}        % used
\usepackage{amsmath}        % used
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % not used
% \usepackage{amsfonts}     % not used
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. Also, you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Does the link suggested by @ TorbjørnT solve your problem?