# Which font am I using

Tags: fonts, matplotlib

I am creating many figures for my LaTeX document using matplotlib with `'text.usetex': True`.

My full preamble looks like this:

```
rc('font', **{'family':'serif', 'serif':['Computer Modern Roman']})
params = {'backend': 'pdf',
          'axes.labelsize': 12,
          'text.fontsize': 12,
          'legend.fontsize': 12,
          'xtick.labelsize': 10,
          'ytick.labelsize': 10,
          'text.usetex': True,
          'figure.figsize': fig_size,
          'axes.unicode_minus': True}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)
```

In the plot I also use `\texttt{}`, which should match the formatting in the latex document. However it doesnt (compare legend and caption, both 12pt).

[image: Matplotlib figure and caption. Typewriter text is rendered differently.]

I assume I have to add something like `'family':'typewriter', 'typewriter':['Some font']`. 
So my questions:

- how can I find out which font and weight is used in the LaTeX document for `\texttt`
- How to tell matplotlib to use the exact same font

Comment: Related: [Set fonts in matplotlib graphs equal to tex document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30998/30999#30999)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matplotlib apparently uses *Courier* as default, my LaTeX uses *Computer Modern Typewriter*.

I found some font specification examples [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html).

So changing the first line of my preamble to

```
rc('font', **{'family':'serif', 'serif':['Computer Modern Roman'], 
                                'monospace': ['Computer Modern Typewriter']})
```

renders the `\texttt{}` the same way LaTeX does.