# Problem resizing vector image: Font is also resized

Tags: graphics, eps, vector, resize

I have created my graph as vector format (.eps) with 12pt title size with Python. However, when I import it in Latex and resize the image (such as `[width = \textwidth]`), as expected, everything gets compressed, even all the text belonging to the figure, what makes me change the size of the script depending on the size that the image is going to have in the document. Is there a way to maintain constant the title and only resize the graph content?

Comment: If the text if part of the image then of course it scales along with the image. There is not much to do here. I always recommend creating the figures in the size they are needed such that one avoids scaling.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You also might use one of LaTeX drawing packages, and play with the unit length. This would not modify the fontsize.

Comment: Depending on which program or library you use there are often also options to export directly to LaTeX code or to image data combined with LaTeX code. For `matplotlib` for example there is PGF export (see https://timodenk.com/blog/exporting-matplotlib-plots-to-latex/ for a small tutorial). In that case the text size is determined by LaTeX so you can scale the image without necessarily scaling the text.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67223/which-font-am-i-using for some more options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciare it. I have seen the tutorial and there are some kind of tips or tricks, but it seems it is not possible unless you resize it matplotlib.